# copy/move all databases from one server to another mysql

Tags: mysql

Currently i have a test server 'X' which has many databases with data in it.I want to copy this data to another server ie 'Y'.Both are on the same mysql version.I read posts regarding the same.I know how to create a sql file and run it.But is there any other quick way without creating sql files for all databases.Should i use replication?is replication applicable in my scenario because there is no master/slave configratn here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below 2 approaches-

**master/Slave:** very less downtime hardly 1 to 10 minutes. As your slave catch the master then you can migrate your site/app to new server.

**Binary Copy:** You can copy all binary files from your mysql data directory and move to new server data directory. It will take time to copy and move your date from one server to another server.

Note: before binary copy you need to take a full dump backup so in case of any issue you are not loosing your data.